# Xamarin Forms: Resource Errors

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, oxyplot

Good Day. I'm creating a Xamarin.Forms (Portable) Application. I'm currently working to have a PieChart using OxyPlot.

I don't know why but suddenly my program displayed **150 ERRORS** and I REALLY DON'T KNOW WHY. Good thing is I was able to find a way to solve it. Simply by deleting all the line of codes with error.

But I don't think this is the best way to do it because everytime I changed something in my code and build it, it displays AGAIN that **150 ERRORS**.

Have you ever experienced this?

Here are the errors:

> Error   CS0117  'Resource.Attribute' does not contain a definition for 'mediaRouteSettingsDrawable' XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    325 149 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Color' does not contain a definition for 'design_textinput_error_color'   XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    475 143 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Dimension' does not contain a definition for 'design_fab_content_size'    XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    583 146 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Dimension' does not contain a definition for 'design_navigation_padding_top_default'  XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    593 160 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Dimension' does not contain a definition for 'design_tab_min_width'   XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    606 143 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Dimension' does not contain a definition for 'dialog_fixed_height_major'  XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    607 148 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Dimension' does not contain a definition for 'dialog_fixed_height_minor'  XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    608 148 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Dimension' does not contain a definition for 'dialog_fixed_width_major'   XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    609 147 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Dimension' does not contain a definition for 'dialog_fixed_width_minor'   XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    610 147 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Dimension' does not contain a definition for 'mr_media_route_controller_art_max_height'   XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    616 163 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Drawable' does not contain a definition for 'ic_setting_dark' XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    704 136 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Drawable' does not contain a definition for 'ic_setting_light'    XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    705 137 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Drawable' does not contain a definition for 'mr_ic_settings_dark' XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    716 140 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Drawable' does not contain a definition for 'mr_ic_settings_light'    XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    717 141 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for 'art'   XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    737 112 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for 'buttons'   XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    741 116 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for 'default_control_frame' XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    756 130 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for 'disconnect'    XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    758 119 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for 'media_route_control_frame' XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    783 134 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for 'media_route_list'  XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    784 125 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for 'media_route_volume_layout' XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    785 134 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for 'media_route_volume_slider' XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    786 134 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for 'play_pause'    XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    796 119 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for 'route_name'    XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    801 119 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for 'settings'  XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    817 117 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for 'stop'  XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    830 113 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for 'subtitle'  XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    832 117 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for 'title_bar' XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    839 118 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Layout' does not contain a definition for 'mr_media_route_chooser_dialog' XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    887 146 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Layout' does not contain a definition for 'mr_media_route_controller_material_dialog_b'   XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    888 160 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Layout' does not contain a definition for 'mr_media_route_list_item'  XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    889 141 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.String' does not contain a definition for 'mr_media_route_button_content_description' XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    922 158 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.String' does not contain a definition for 'mr_media_route_chooser_searching'  XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    923 149 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.String' does not contain a definition for 'mr_media_route_chooser_title'  XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    924 145 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.String' does not contain a definition for 'mr_media_route_controller_disconnect'  XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    925 153 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.String' does not contain a definition for 'mr_media_route_controller_no_info_available'   XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    926 160 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.String' does not contain a definition for 'mr_media_route_controller_pause'   XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    927 148 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.String' does not contain a definition for 'mr_media_route_controller_play'    XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    928 147 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.String' does not contain a definition for 'mr_media_route_controller_settings_description'    XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    929 163 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.String' does not contain a definition for 'mr_media_route_controller_stop'    XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    930 147 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Style' does not contain a definition for 'RtlOverlay_Widget_AppCompat_ActionButton_Overflow'  XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1092    164 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'FloatingActionButton_android_background'    XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1371    162 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_actionBarDivider' XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1524    145 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_actionBarItemBackground'  XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1525    152 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_actionBarPopupTheme'  XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1526    148 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_actionBarSize'    XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1527    142 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_actionBarSplitStyle'  XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1528    148 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_actionBarStyle'   XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1529    143 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_actionBarTabBarStyle' XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1530    149 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_actionBarTabStyle'    XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1531    146 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_actionBarTabTextStyle'    XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1532    150 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_actionBarTheme'   XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1533    143 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_actionBarWidgetTheme' XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1534    149 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_actionButtonStyle'    XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1535    146 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_actionDropDownStyle'  XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1536    148 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_actionMenuTextAppearance' XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1537    153 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_actionMenuTextColor'  XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1538    148 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_actionModeBackground' XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1539    149 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_actionModeCloseButtonStyle'   XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1540    155 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_actionModeCloseDrawable'  XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1541    152 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_actionModeCopyDrawable'   XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1542    151 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_actionModeCutDrawable'    XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1543    150 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_actionModeFindDrawable'   XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1544    151 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_actionModePasteDrawable'  XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1545    152 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_actionModePopupWindowStyle'   XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1546    155 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_actionModeSelectAllDrawable'  XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1547    156 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_actionModeShareDrawable'  XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1548    152 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_actionModeSplitBackground'    XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1549    154 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_actionModeStyle'  XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1550    144 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_actionModeWebSearchDrawable'  XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1551    156 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_actionOverflowButtonStyle'    XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1552    154 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_actionOverflowMenuStyle'  XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1553    152 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_activityChooserViewStyle' XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1554    153 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_alertDialogButtonGroupStyle'  XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1555    156 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_alertDialogCenterButtons' XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1556    153 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_alertDialogStyle' XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1557    145 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_alertDialogTheme' XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1558    145 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_android_windowAnimationStyle' XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1559    157 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_android_windowIsFloating' XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1560    153 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_autoCompleteTextViewStyle'    XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1561    154 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_borderlessButtonStyle'    XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1562    150 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_buttonBarButtonStyle' XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1563    149 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle' XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1564    157 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle'  XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1565    156 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle' XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1566    157 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_buttonBarStyle'   XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1567    143 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_buttonStyle'  XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1568    140 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_buttonStyleSmall' XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1569    145 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_checkboxStyle'    XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1570    142 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_checkedTextViewStyle' XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1571    149 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_colorAccent'  XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1572    140 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_colorButtonNormal'    XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1573    146 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_colorControlActivated'    XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1574    150 Active
>   Error   CS0117  'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_colorControlHighlight'    XamarinFormsDemo.Droid  C:\Users\LIFEBOOK E743\Desktop\EBMS FILES\Kims File\72516\XamarinFormsDemo\XamarinFormsDemo.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs    1575    150 Active

Comment: What is the Minimum and Target Android version? You can find it in Project Options/Build/Android Application

Comment: @Prashant Sir my Minimum version is Android 4.0.3 (API Level 15 - Ice Cream Sandwich) but I don't set the Target Android Version.

Comment: are you using xlabs library?

Comment: @batmaci no Sir I'm not using xLabs.

Answer (score 2):

This error can have various reasons. Please check through each of them.

1. Delete Bin and Obj folders in project folder.Clean %temp% folder.
       Delete contents of C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips 
       Rebuild your application.
2. Update to latest [Java SE Development Kit Update 79](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) or higher. I
   had Java SE Development Kit Update 55 and caused me those
       errors
3. If any of your images names contains "-" (dash) in android project.
   remove dashes.
4. if you are using xlab, latest stable xlab version is not compatible
       with latest XF version. you find more details and
   solution [here](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/issues/1125). It is suggested to use XLabs.Forms 2.2.0-pre05
5. Make sure you have the correct android api SDKis installed. In order to check Android Api SDK, click the menu button on VS 2015 menu as in the image below.
   [image]
6. If any of those doesnt work for you, try to uninstall and install all your libraries. Especially Xamarin libraries.

Comment: Sir how will I know if I have installed the correct android api level?

Comment: how will i know Sir if i have installed the correct android api level?

Comment: @JayceeEvangelista please see my updated answer. click the button in the image and it will open a popup. there you can see which android api sdk you have installed

Comment: Sir It is installed. But how will I know if that's the correct android api SDK? here's my screenshot. http://prntscr.com/bxoryl

Comment: @JayceeEvangelista Did you check the other points. especially with java SDK and images? these are more common than Android Api SDK

Comment: Not yet Sir. I'm using Visual Studio 2015. How can I do your point no.2?

Comment: @JayceeEvangelista it is nothing to do with the VS. just click the link there and download, install. but first check your each images if they have dash in the name

Comment: my images don't have dashes Sir. After downloading jdk 79, what should I do with this?

Comment: Install it but I think you should follow each steps first. you are jumping from one to another. I wrote you the steps in importance order.

Comment: I followed you steps Sir. I tried no.1, no.2 (just now), no.3, and no.5. I'm not yet in step no.6. About the step no. 4, I don't have xLabs installed in my pc Sir.

Comment: what do I need to do now Sir?